# Java Programming Help for 2 files with a controlling class

Tags: java, class, methods

First java class is the primary one which invokes other classes.  I will copy the code for the two files.  I cannot compile this code and I do not know why.

When I had the program in one file it ran fine, but the instructor wants it in two files.  Can someone explain to me what I am doing, or did incorrectly?

File 1:

```
public class Wk2ToddFoughty {        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SalaryCalc FinalSalaryCalc = new SalaryCalc();            
        FinalSalaryCalc.SalaryCalc();               
    }
}
```

File 2:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class SalaryCalc {                                  
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your annual sales: $");          
      double sales = in.nextDouble();
      double salary = 35000.00;
      double commission = (sales * .015);
      double totalSalary = salary + sales;
      System.out.println("Your Salary + Commission is: $" + totalSalary );   
}
```

Comment: In file 2, did you forget to copy in the method?

Comment: where is your method in file 2?

Comment: Method description is not found in class 2.

Comment: Take some time editing your question with the following: Error messages if you have some and fix your snippets of code (it seems like you forgot the method in file 2). :)

Comment: `System.out.println();` statements belong inside a method or constructor.

Comment: Is the `SalaryCalc` method declared `static`? If so, replace `SalaryCalc FinalSalaryCalc = new SalaryCalc(); FinalSalaryCalc.SalaryCalc(); ` with `SalaryCalc.SalaryCalc;`. But that's just a guess, please provide a compiling example of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to understand if you kept to Java naming conventions - also see inline comments

```
public class Wk2ToddFoughty {        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SalaryCalc myCalc = new SalaryCalc();  //  SalaryCalc - name of class
                                               // myCalc - name of object            
        myCalc.doCalc();                       // doCalc - name of method (missing from your class)           
    }
}

// edit this class to add missing method

public class SalaryCalc {                                  

      public void doCalc () {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your annual sales: $");          
        double sales = in.nextDouble();
        double salary = 35000.00;
        double commission = (sales * .015);
        double totalSalary = salary + sales;
        System.out.println("Your Salary + Commission is: $" + totalSalary );   

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you and everyone else who commented.  I know it can be frustrating helping newbies out.  I am still getting errors when I try to compile the code of cannot find symbol Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);.  This seems to be where it fails before, and I do not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Your second file doesn't define a method called `SalaryCalc`. You should also honor standard Java naming practices, and keep input/output logic outside of your business classes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Wk2ToddFoughty {        
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your annual sales: $");   
        SalaryCalc calc = new SalaryCalc(35000);
        double totalSalary = calc.calcSalary(in.nextDouble());    
        System.out.println("Your Salary + Commission is: $" + totalSalary);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SalaryCalc {
    private double salary;

    public SalaryCalc(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public void calcSalary(double sales) {
        double commission = sales * 0.015;
        return salary + sales + commission;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I know assisting newbies can be frustrating.  I tried your code and received errors.  C:\Users\TMFoughty\Desktop\java>javac Wk2ToddFoughty.java
Wk2ToddFoughty.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class Wk2ToddFoughty
Wk2ToddFoughty.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                         ^
  symbol:   class Scanner

Comment: This seems to be where I am going wrong, this seems to be the error I get most of the time.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying attention to the imports. You have to import `Scanner` at the top of the file it's used in.